# Matrix is zero after assignment. C++Armadillo

Tags: c++, matrix, armadillo

I have a code in VS2015 V140, with Armadillo library.

B_lin is defined as:

```
mat B_lin(4, 2, fill::zeros);
```

and in the middle of the code there are lines :

```
.
.
.


        B_lin(0, 0) = -(2/3)*9.8*sin(alpha)*sin(theta);
        B_lin(0, 1) = -(2 / 3)*9.8*cos(alpha)*cos(theta);
        B_lin(2, 0) = (2/3)*9.8*cos(alpha);
        cout<< B_lin;

.
.
.
```

And nothing else before these lines affecting B_lin.

Alpha and theta are 0.05 both (these are also intact up to this line).

But it shows B_lin is all zeros.

Thanks in advance

Comment: alpha and theta are doubles.

Comment: (2/3) evaluates to integer zero. At least one of them have to be a double, eg (2.0/3).

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you. I knew when dividing an integer it converts the result to int, but did not know it also applies here.